# Gitlab code owners for nested folders is not being applied

Tags: gitlab, codeowners

sample

users - u1, u2, u3, u4, u5

project

- web ( can be approved by u1, u2, u3, u4, u5 )
- web/helpers/
- web/utils/
- web/pages/home/

above can be approved by anyone who can approve web repo

- web/pages/dashboard/ ( can be approved by u1 )
- web/atoms/ ( can be approved by u4, u5 )
- web/pages/profile/ ( can be approved by u4, u3 )

Code owners is not considering the nested rules

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your actual `CODEOWNERS` file (obfuscate the users)